# File copy between two ftp servers from a (third) local machine

Tags: ftp, files

I have two ftp servers A and B. I need to copy a certain directory tree (and all files under it) from server A to server B. Is there a way to achieve this from my local machine (c) without having to run anything on server A and B?

*EDIT* All the three machines are on different networks but I have access to both the servers from my local m/c. Server B is a Akamai server (guessing it's linux) where we are hosting content and need to replicate content from the ftp server A (also a linux server)

Comment: Need more info - like, how are all these machines connected? And what Operating system is running? Are they all on the same network? Are they windows machines on a domain? Are there firewalls between the systems?

Comment: edited the question to address the details you asked for

Comment: Transferring from one FTP Server to another directly requires FXP support, which most servers do not have. Similarly the client needs to support it, or you'd have to issue commands manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work the FTP servers you are connecting to must not explicitly prohibit server to server connection.  You need a client capable of controlling the server to server request request.

The method for performing a server to server transfer is the same method used for an [FTP Bounce Attack](http://www.cert.org/advisories/CA-1997-27.html), so the server to server functionality is often prohibited by the configuration, or it is not even supported in some FTP servers.

Proftpd has a nice description of how the transfer takes place, and what you would have to do to make this supported under [Proftpd](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/FXP.html).

Since you have no control of the two ftp servers in question, you almost certainly can't configure them to support the server to server communication.  Since supporting server-to-server communication is disabled by default on almost every ftp daemon these days, it is unlikely that you will be able to make this work.